# Data sets of questions asked in conferences

Tags: conference, reference-request, data

I am looking for data sets of questions asked in academic conferences. Ideally, it should contain a timestamped transcript as well as some reference to the talk (e.g. the paper it was presenting), but a simple list of questions would be already of interest to me.

I am mostly interested in the field of computer science (natural language processing and machine learning), and English-speaking venues.

Comment: @ThejusMahajan 1. Reference requests are on-topic 2. The question will help people like me.

Comment: I've never heard of any such data being gathered.  Presumably, if questions at a conference were going to be recorded and transcribed, and the data made available for use in research, the participants would all have to give informed consent, and I've never heard of a conference asking for such consent.

Comment: I recall having seen very old conference proceedings reporting questions and replies, but nothing in recent times, so I don't think they are typically collected.

Comment: No conference I ever attended did record questions

Comment: @vonbrand http://videolectures.net/ . Maybe someone took care of the ASR.

Answer (score 4):

Such a data set probably does not exist, due to human subjects considerations.  While conference speakers are often asked to consent to possible recording of their talks, conference attendees are not generally asked for such consent.  Sometimes questioners do get recorded anyway, in those rare talks that actually are recorded, but they have certainly not provided any explicit consent for becoming experimental subjects.

Now, some researcher and their IRB might well be able to work out a way to build a data set from the decidedly biased sample of publicly available talks that happen to include questions. Doing so and then executing that project, however, is likely to be a rather large research and coding effort and with that much work the authors would certainly end up wanting to publish papers on it.

In short: if your literature search isn't turning it up already, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: http://videolectures.net/ does manage to record some conference talks. Also, there is no IRB in Europe, so it may be easier in some countries.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I believe that many other countries have strong requirements for assurance of ethics in research as well: see [the HHS International Compilation of Human Research Standards](http://www.hhs.gov/ohrp/international/index.html)